# Jquery send the email with attachments

Tags: php, jquery, email, email-attachments

I am working on the jquery to upload the attachments so I can post the files name via ajax. I have got a problem with storing the files name in the array and display each file name in the loop, because it will store 2 files name in the array in one index using this code:

```
$(".file-list_yhs").each(function() {
    attachments[i++] = $(this).find('.vI').text();
});
```

Output:

```
Array
{
    [0] => uploads/add email.txtemail.zip
}
Array
```

It should be:

```
Array
{
    [0] => uploads/add email.txt
}
Array
{
    [1] => uploads/email.zip
}
```

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).on('click','#domodal_send', function(e) {

    if ($(".notify-outer").css('display') == 'none') {

        var email = $("#domodal_email_receipt").val();
        var subject = $("#domodal_subject").val();
        var from_name = $("#avater_name").text();
        var from_email = $('#avater_email').text();
        var emailbody = $("#domodal_message").html();
        var attachments = [];
        var i = 0;

        $(".file-list_yhs").each(function() {
            attachments[i++] = $(this).find('.vI').text();
        });


         $.ajax({
                url: 'sendMail.php',
                type: 'POST',

                data : {
                    send_to: email,
                    from: from_name,
                    from_email: from_email,
                    emailsubject: subject,
                    emailbody: emailbody,
                    emailattachment: attachments
                },

                success: function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                }
         });
    }
});
```

SendMail.php:

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once "Mail/mime.php";
require_once('Mail/IMAPv2.php');

//Connect to the database
include('config.php');

$inbox = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$mailserver = '{imap.example.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX.Sent';

if (isset($_POST['send_to']))
{
    $from = "Robert <rob@example.com>";
    $to_email = $_POST['send_to'];
    $to = $firstname . " <$to_email>";
    $subject = $_POST['emailsubject'];
    $message = $_POST['emailbody'];
    $message_without_image = $_POST['emailbody'];
    $filenames =  $_POST['emailattachment'];
    $files = [];

    foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
        $files[] = 'uploads/' . $filename;
    }
    print_r($files);

    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $smtp_hostname = "smtp.example.com";
    $port = "587";
    echo $files;

    /*$messageID = sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
            base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
            base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
            'example.com');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $emailID = '';
    $sent_db = "SELECT email_id FROM sent WHERE email_id = '$messageID'";
    $sent_result = mysqli_query($link, $sent_db) or die($link->error);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($sent_result) == 0)
    {
        $sent_db1 = "INSERT INTO sent (id, email_id, email, sendDateTime, isRead, readDateTIme) VALUES ('', '$messageID', '$to', '$date', '0', '0000-00-00 00:00:00')";

        if (mysqli_query($link, $sent_db1)) {
            $emailID = mysqli_insert_id($link);
        }
    }
    $message .= "<img src=\"http://test.example.com/project/track/Images/signature.gif?id=".$emailID."&etc=".time()." \" style=\"width: 0; max-height:0; overflow:hidden; \">";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from, 
        'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject,
        'Reply-To' => $from,
        'Content-Type'  => 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        'MIME-Version' => '1.0',
        'Received' => 'from smtp.example.com',
        'Date'  => date("r"),
        'Message-ID' => sprintf("<%s.%s@%s>",
            base_convert(microtime(), 10, 36),
            base_convert(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8)), 16, 36),
            'example.com'));

    $params = array ('host' => $smtp_hostname,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => 'PLAIN', // Note 1
        'socket_options' => array('ssl' => array('verify_peer_name' => false, 'verify_peer' => false)), // Note 2
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password);

    $mime_params = array(
        'text_encoding' => '7bit',
        'text_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'html_charset'  => 'UTF-8',
        'head_charset'  => 'UTF-8'
    );

    $crlf = "\r\n";
    $mime = new Mail_mime(array('eol' => $crlf));
    $body = $message;

    $mime->setTXTBody($body);
    $mime->setHTMLBody($body);

    if(!empty($files)) {
        $mime->addAttachment($files);
    }
    $body = $mime->get($mime_params);
    $headers = $mime->headers($headers);
    $smtp = Mail::factory ('smtp', $params);
    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
    {
        echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
    }
    else 
    {
        echo("<p>Email has been sent!</p>");
    }
}
?>
```

What I am trying to do is to store the files name in the array and post it via ajax after I have uploaded the files on my server. When the files is upload on the server, I can be able to output each files name to add the files location on the server and send the email with the attachments.

Can you please show me an example how I could store each file name in the loop where I could use it to post it with ajax to output each file name?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the html:

```
<div style="width: 70%; margin-left: 10px; position:relative;" class="file-list_yhs">
  <div class="dL" tabindex="-1" id=":vw" aria-label="Attachment: edit_link1.png. Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it" style="position:relative;">
    <input id=":vp" name="attach" type="hidden" value="#msg-a:r-6685135251679589431_#msg-a:r-6685135251679589431_null_-1" checked="">
    <div style="display:flex">
      <a class="dO" id=":vq" style="display:flex;">
        <div id="domodal_attachment" class="vI">addd her email.txt</div>
        <div class="vJ">(0K)</div>
      </a>
      <div id=":vn" role="button" aria-label="Remove attachment" class="vq" tabindex="-1" data-tooltip="Remove attachment" style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px;"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="dL" tabindex="-1" id=":vw" aria-label="Attachment: edit_link1.png. Press enter to view the attachment and delete to remove it" style="position:relative;">
    <input id=":vp" name="attach" type="hidden" value="#msg-a:r-6685135251679589431_#msg-a:r-6685135251679589431_null_-1" checked="">
    <div style="display:flex">
      <a class="dO" id=":vq" style="display:flex;">
        <div id="domodal_attachment" class="vI">email.zip</div>
        <div class="vJ">(183K)</div>
      </a>
      <div id=":vn" role="button" aria-label="Remove attachment" class="vq" tabindex="-1" data-tooltip="Remove attachment" style="position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the part where you populate `attachments` in your "full code". Where is it located in that code?

Comment: @showdev the full code is located in index.php and the code for the send email is located in sendmail.php. Do you want me to add the code for the attachments the one that I upload the files to my server?

Comment: It's just that I don't see the `attachments[i++] = $(this).find('.vI').text();` part in the section where you say "Here is the full code".

Comment: Oh, the `attachments` is just an array as I am using it to store the filename. Do you want to see the html that come with `vI` as a class?

Comment: @showdev Oh sorry I have forgot to include the `attachments[i++] = $(this).find('.vI').text();` part in the full code so I have updated it. Please see in my updated question.

Comment: Why do you expect to see two different `Array{...}` values? I think you should expect `Array{[0] => uploads/add email.txt [1] => uploads/email.zip}`

Comment: Use `attachments.push()` instead of `attachments[i++]`, although I don't think it should make a difference.

Comment: Can you add the HTML that shows `.file-list_yhs`?

Comment: @Barmar sure...

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the html code in my question. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating an array element for each `.file-list_yhs` DIV, not for each `.vI` DIV. `$(this).find('.vI').text()` will concatenate the texts of all the `.vI` elements that it finds in each `.file-list_yhs`.

Change your loop to

```
$(".file-list_yhs .vI").each(function() {
    attachments.push($(this).text());
}
```

You can also use `.map`:

```
attachments = $(".file-list_yhs .vI").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

`.get()` is needed at the end to convert the jQuery object that `.map()` returns to an array.

Comment: thank you very much for this, I can see the first code for the loop is working great as I am getting this now `Array
{
    [0] => add email.txt
}
Array
{
    [1] => email.zip
}`. Problem are now resolved.

Comment: You should be getting `Array { [0] => add email.txt  [1] => email.zip }`

Comment: yes i did now thank you for your help. Problem are now resolved.